# Is it possible for my linux machine (with no GUI) to hit Twitter sign up page, and then spit out a captcha in a webpage format

Tags: python, http, forms, twitter, captcha

So that I can just type in the letters and register (through my linux box's IP)?

(twitter uses recaptcha)

Is there some way to grab that javascript, output it into a webpage. Then submit it through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter offers a special [API for services](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/). Use that to automatically login from one of your programs to post tweets.